# Can not point to Selenium Webdriver path for Python Jupyter Notebook on Azure

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jupyter-notebook

I am running Python Jupyter notebooks on https://notebooks.azure.com in browser (can't install anything on my office laptop, and this has been a salvation), but for Selenium framework, I am unable to make WebDriver work - the error message:

*WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home*

Also, uploading the chromedriver.exe file to library and directly pointing to it did not help either.

*driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/nbuser/library/chromedriver.exe')*

Any suggestions for a solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Anybody, somebody..?

Comment: did you find a solution?